# Focus Textbox After User Submits Form

Tags: vb.net, textbox, focus, submit, pageload

Based on my coding I want to focus the textbox which flags the messagebox.

If I do `FocusText = Password2` after the `Response.Write` the `Response.Write` won't work.

Therefore I tried to make a global variable for FocusText (and remove the line after `Response.Write`), but the "Page load" declaration for `Password1` seems to override it no matter what. How do I correct this?

**Ex of what I want:**

- When page loads, cursor focuses on Password1.
- Password2 text box isn't filled in after user clicks submit button. The code will flag with `Response.Write` and then focus the cursor back to Password2.

-Same scenario if user doesn't fill in `Company Name`, `federal tax` etc....

```
Public Class Supplier
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public Shared FocusText As TextBox

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'LocalUnionText.Text.Visible = False
    'Dim focusP As TextBox = Password2
    'focusP.Focus()
    FocusText = Password1

    FocusText.Focus()
End Sub

Protected Sub Register_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Register.Click
    Dim tax_id_text As String
    tax_id_text = FED_TAX_ID.Text

    Dim FocusText As TextBox
    Dim FocusDrop As DropDownList

    If Password1.Text.Length <> 0 Then
        'Password2
        If Password2.Text.Length <> 0 Then
            'FedTax
            If FED_TAX_ID.Text.Length <> 0 Then
                If COMPANY_NAME.Text.Length <> 0 Then
                    If StrEET_ADDR.Text.Length <> 0 Then
                        If CITY.Text.Length <> 0 Then
                            If StatesList.Text <> "Select Option" Then
                                If ZIP_CODE.Text.Length <> 0 Then
                                    If PHONE.Text.Length <> 0 Then
                                    Else
                                        Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Please enter a Phone Number');</script>")
                                        FocusText = PHONE
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Please enter a Zip code');</script>")
                                    FocusText = ZIP_CODE
                                End If
                            Else
                                Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Please select a State');</script>")
                                FocusDrop = StatesList
                            End If
                        Else
                            Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Please enter a City');</script>")
                            FocusText = CITY
                    End If
                Else
                        Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Please enter a Street');</script>")
                        FocusText = COMPANY_NAME
                End If
            Else
                    Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Please enter a Comapny Name');</script>")
                    FocusText = FED_TAX_ID
            End If
        Else
                Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Please enter a federal tax ID');</script>")
                FocusText = Password2
        End If
        Else
            Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Both Passwords don't match. Please try again.');</script>")
            FocusText = Password2
        End If
    Else
        Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Please enter a Password');</script>")
        FocusText = Password1
    End If

    'FocusText.Focus()
    'FocusDrop.Focus()
End Sub
```

**UPDATE** I tried to add a label but I have to click the submit button twice for the focus to register (I think the time the label changes to when the page reloads is off) **Not sure why?**

```
Public Class SupplierUpdate
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public Shared FocusTextv As TextBox
Public Shared myControl1 As Control

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'LocalUnionText.Text.Visible = False
    'Dim focusP As TextBox = Password2
    'focusP.Focus()
    myControl1 = FindControl(FocusText.Text)
    FocusTextv = myControl1

    FocusTextv.Focus()
..etc
```

Reponse.Write Change

```
Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Please enter a Owner Phone Extension');</script>")

FocusText.Text = "OWNERPHONEEXT"
```

Label Added

```
<asp:Label ID="FocusText" runat="server" hidden="true">Password1</asp:Label>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `Response.Write` parts to look like this (additions to my updates):

```
Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Please enter a Owner Phone Extension');</script>")

FocusText.Text = "OWNERPHONEEXT"
myControl1 = FindControl(FocusText.Text)

FocusTextV = myControl1
FocusTextV.Focus()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Response.Write` is writing a JavaScript that displays an `alert`, which is modal dialog. You cannot have any focus while the `alert` is displayed, but the focus will work after you hit the OK button.

If you use a label on the page to display your message instead of the `alert`, the focus will work.

Note: It is probably better to use the ASP.Net Validation Controls as they provide all the functionality that you're trying to implement here.

**Update** It's hard to follow the changes in your update, but I will try.

The `Page_Load` should not have any code for the `Focus`, so remove those tree lines that you have now in your update:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'LocalUnionText.Text.Visible = False
    'Dim focusP As TextBox = Password2
    'focusP.Focus()
    'myControl1 = FindControl(FocusText.Text)
    'FocusTextv = myControl1
    'FocusTextv.Focus()
..etc
```

Then in `Register_Click`, replace every `Response.Write` with `FocusText.Text = "..."`. For example, change:

```
Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Please enter a Phone Number');</script>")
```

to:

```
FocusText.Text ="Please enter a Phone Number"
```

The ID of your new `Label` conflict with the name of one of your variables, so change it to something else. Also you don't need to hide it, just leave it empty (with no text). Example:

```
<asp:Label ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

And at the bottom of `Register_Click`:

```
'FocusText.Focus()
```

Comment: please look at my update. I tried your suggestion. It almost works but the page needs to be re-loaded twice to focus?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Oops. I've just posted an update for you before I noticed your comment and answer. You don't need to use `FindControl`, check my update.

Comment: The FocusText.Text is just to hold the textbox's ID that needs to be focused, so that the FocusTextv(created Textbox) could call the .Focus(requires a textbox value instead of a string value).  So your example wouldn't completely work because I need a window pop-up alert that the user didn't fill the textbox, not a html text on the page. I appreciate your example tho :)

Comment: I see. That's the problem when you don't post all the relevant code, we cannot offer an accurate answer. So have you solved all the issues now, or do you still need some help?

Comment: What I posted is the relevant code tho? I showed that my pop-up text is different than my FocusText.Text so I didn't think that I needed to state more than that. Also, Focus.() can only take textboxes by default so my coding shows that I am trying to pull a textbox.

Comment: I also can't accept my answer until 2 hours from now

Comment: Of course you provided relevant code, but not ALL the relevant code :-). You did not provide the UI code, so we don't know the exact design, we can only guess. I'm glad you loved it, though.